# cakephp 3 - validate fields to contains characters only

Tags: cakephp-3.4

i'm basically trying to check if a field contains characters only instead of string or integers tried using custom() method to return regex true or false but giving error maybe syntax error quite new to cake 3

```
  $validator
         ->requirePresence('field','create')
         ->notEmpty('field')
          ->add('field','custom', ['check' => 'field', 'regex' => ['A-Za-z']
            ['message' => 'chars only']);
```

giving this error below...

Unable to call method "" in "default" provider for field "field"

Comment: You can try this 

 ` $validator->add('field', 'validFormat',[
                'rule' => array('custom', '/^([A-Za-z])$/i'),
                'message' => 'chars only.'
        ]);`

Comment: thanks for that fam!

Answer (score -1):

->add('field',[ 'custom' => [ 'check' => 'field', 'regex' => '/[A-Za-z
]/', 'message' => (__("Only Alphabets Allowed")), ] ] );